# What makes cooking tomatoes on copper unsafe?

Tags: food-safety, food-poisoning

I have heard that tomatoes were thought to be poisonous because they were prepared by cooking on a copper pan. Is this true and what compounds or chemicals are made that make it poisonous?

Comment: Heard where? What evidence do you have to back this up?

Comment: @JJosaur None, just here say

Comment: I'd change your question to "Does cooking tomatoes in copper generate any negative side-effects?"